# UWP how to set Text Alignment in ContentPresenter

Tags: xaml, uwp

[wrapped text will keep center not left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PifRy.png)

Is there any way to setup text wrapping so that all of the text in the text block is center-aligned?

```
 <ContentPresenter        x:Name="CPMessage"
                                      Content="{Binding BodyContent, ElementName=control, Mode=OneWay}"
                                      Margin="32,0,32,36"
                                      TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                      FontSize="16" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it pretty easily by myself with the below code

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BodyContent, ElementName=control, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                   TextAlignment="Center" />
```

Add the code inside of COntentPresenter